# ansible-playbook acting differently when called in a bash script to directly on shell

Tags: bash, ansible

When I use the `remote.sh` to execute the ansible-playbook, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: "monitoring"
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

When I execute it directly, it's working as expected.

```
ansible-playbook --inventory /ansible/remote_hosts.yml --ask-vault-pass --extra-vars "@/ansible/vars/vault.yml" --limit "monitoring" /ansible/playbooks/playbook.yml
```

I don't get what makes the difference. What do I need to check to get the script working?

My setup is as followed:

remote.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
limit="--limit \"monitoring\""

function playbookRemote() {
    if [[ -z ${limit} ]]; then
        limit=''
    fi

    if [[ -z ${tags} ]]; then
        tags=''
    fi

    echo "ansible-playbook --inventory $(pwd)/remote_hosts.yml --ask-vault-pass --extra-vars \"@$(pwd)/vars/vault.yml\" ${limit} $(pwd)/playbooks/playbook.yml"
    ansible-playbook \
        --inventory $(pwd)/remote_hosts.yml \
        --ask-vault-pass \
        --extra-vars "@$(pwd)/vars/vault.yml" \
        ${limit} \
        ${tags} \
        $(pwd)/playbooks/playbook.yml
}
playbookRemote
```

remote_hosts.yml

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    corp:
      hosts:
        monitoring:
          ansible_host: 192.168.0.159
          ansible_user: corpadmin
          ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ansible_password: '{{ monitoring_password }}'
          ansible_become: True
          ansible_become_pass: '{{ monitoring_password }}'
```

playbook.yml

```yaml
---
- hosts: corp
  gather_facts: true

  roles:
    - php
    - geerlingguy.mysql
    - mariadb
    - apache
    - geerlingguy.apache
    - geerlingguy.certbot
```

vault.yml

```yaml
---
monitoring_password: ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually problem in your `bash` script, not with ansible.
Like this (`limit="--limit \"monitoring\""`), the quotes are part of `limit`, they will not get removed, so ansible receives `"monitoring"`, which it does not know, it knows `monitoring`.
Remove those quotes and it works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
limit="--limit monitoring"

function playbookRemote() {
    if [[ -z ${limit} ]]; then
        limit=''
    fi

    if [[ -z ${tags} ]]; then
        tags=''
    fi

    echo "ansible-playbook --inventory $(pwd)/remote_hosts.yml --ask-vault-pass --extra-vars \"@$(pwd)/vars/vault.yml\" ${limit} $(pwd)/playbooks/playbook.yml"
    ansible-playbook \
        --inventory $(pwd)/remote_hosts.yml \
        --ask-vault-pass \
        --extra-vars "@$(pwd)/vars/vault.yml" \
        ${limit} \
        ${tags} \
        $(pwd)/playbooks/playbook.yml
}
playbookRemote
```

Comment: You are right. Removing the quotes fixed the problem. Thanks for hinting.